# javascript is not working on first load - works after a refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I test this the first time round (fresh browser- cleared cache),

it does not work as expected.

Once I refresh, it works perfectly well.

i think missing something

here i attach the full script, please help

```
<script>
                    //get the IP addresses associated with an account
                    function getIPs(callback){
                        var ip_dups = {};

                        //compatibility for firefox and chrome
                        var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                            || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                            || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                        var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

                        //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
                        if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                            //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                            //
                            //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                            //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                            //
                            var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                            RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                                || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                                || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                            useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                        }

                        //minimal requirements for data connection
                        var mediaConstraints = {
                            optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
                        };

                        var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

                        //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
                        var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

                        function handleCandidate(candidate){
                            //match just the IP address
                            var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                            var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

                            //remove duplicates
                            if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                                callback(ip_addr);

                            ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
                        }

                        //listen for candidate events
                        pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

                            //skip non-candidate events
                            if(ice.candidate)
                                handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
                        };

                        //create a bogus data channel
                        pc.createDataChannel("");

                        //create an offer sdp
                        pc.createOffer(function(result){

                            //trigger the stun server request
                            pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

                        }, function(){});

        //read candidate info from local description
        var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

        lines.forEach(function(line){
        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
        handleCandidate(line);
        });
                    }

                    //insert IP addresses into the page
                    getIPs(function(ip){

                        //local IPs
                        if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                           //document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
        document.cookie="ip="+ip;
                    });


                </script>
```

This script is not working in safari browser also, but this one is working in chrome, opera and Firefox also

please help me for this issue,

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Safari has mitigations for the "ip leak" issue described [here](https://webkit.org/blog/7763/a-closer-look-into-webrtc/). WebRTC was not designed for gathering IP address from users without their consent.